# Documentation of System.Aura class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, aura

Based on the comments in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/187283/38396) answer, Salesforce uses `System.Aura` class in the implementation of their auto-generated components. Could anyone share any pieces of documentation related to it, specifically:

- what methods are available?
- what can these methods do and what is the expected outcome of these methods?

Answer (score 5):

Was looking at this with a colleague yesterday.

What we got to was that there are two methods in the class. We drew this conclusion from auto-complete in developer console:

[image]

As for the documented behaviour of these, your guess is as good as mine. Clearly, redirect seems to perform a redirect :)